# SAML validation issues

Tags: single-sign-on, saml

Setting up SSO with Google as an IDP and Salesforce as a service provider.

I see the following when validating SAML:

```
 Current time is after notOnOrAfter in Conditions
  Current time is: 2024-01-11T17:31:52.529Z
  Time limit in Conditions, adjusted for skew, is: 2024-01-11T15:56:19.243Z
  Timestamp of the response is outside of allowed time window
  Current time is: 2024-01-11T17:31:52.529Z
  Timestamp is: 2024-01-11T15:48:19.243Z
  Allowed skew in milliseconds is 480000
  Timestamp of the assertion is outside of allowed time window
  Current time is: 2024-01-11T17:31:52.529Z
  Timestamp is: 2024-01-11T15:48:19.243Z
  Allowed skew in milliseconds is 480000
```

I understand there is an allowed skew here of 8 minutes, and this is outside of that time window, but is there a way to adjust this on the Salesforce end (either making it more lax or using an Apex interface)?

I haven't the slightest clue where I can start adjusting this to be even close to 8 minutes.

Comment: No, you won't be able to adjust it.

Comment: @identigral In that case, SSO with Google is just something that I can't do without OATH?

Comment: Google does not issue assertions that are minutes behind, you're copying and pasting an old assertion.